# Persnickety AWS Chatbot won't send messages to slack except for the test message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-chatbot

I've got a SNS topic setup that has two subscribers:

1. The AWS Chatbot
2. An Email Address

If I sent a test message in the AWS console using the "Send Test Message" button in the AWS Chatbot UI then the message is seen both subscribers and I see a message sent to the slack channel and delivered to my email address.  However, if I publish a message using the aws cli or even using the AWS Console "Publish Message" button in the SNS topic UI only the email subscriber delivers the message to my inbox.  I never see those messages in slack from the AWS chatbot.

So I figured out the test message that AWS Chatbot was delivering, and it's a JSON object like this (I've added spacing to help with readability):

```
{
   "source":"chatbot",
   "notificationType":"ChatbotSystemTest",
   "notificationSource":"sns",
   "configurationName":"awschat-bot-slack-engineering",
   "workspaceId":"1231231231231"
}
```

If I publish that exact message in either the AWS console with Publish Message or the aws cli then it will post to slack.  Here is an example of how I'm publishing the message that the chatbot will pass along to slack.

```
 aws sns publish \
   --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:xxxxx:xxxxxxx:topicName \
   --message '{"source":"solr,"notificationType":"ChatbotSystemTest","notificationSource":"sns","configurationName":"awschat-bot-slack-engineering","workspaceId":"xxxxxxx"}'
```

However, if I modify that message by changing the `source` or `notificationType` it doesn't show up in slack.  The email subscriber still delivers the message every time without judgement.

So why is the AWS Chatbot being so GD persnickety?

Comment: Could you please clarify your setup and the steps you've been doing so far? "sent to both subscribers": what are those? "If I send that exact message": where are you sending it and what command exactly are you running? Thank you.

Comment: The term subscribers are what AWS SNS calls the consumers of the messages posted to the SNS Topic.  When I say send I mean publish the message to the topic, but when I say a subscriber sends I mean the subscriber passes along that message to the respective endpoint.  You can read it as delivers if that helps.  I've added the AWS cli command I used to publish messages from my EC2 servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must avail yourself of any pretenses that reading the documentation shouldn't be required for such a modest feature.  Nay! For you may NOT just send ANY old message to AWS Chatbot.  Heavens no for that would offend its magnificent engineering decisions to only support certain services and certain messages.  You must conduct yourselves in a becoming manner and send a "Customized Notification".  And hence your message must conform to the particulars of JSON and AWS Chatbot's most royal JSON format. The minimal of messages bearing this un-awkward format is thusly:

```
{
   "version": "1.0", 
   "source":"custom", 
   "content": { 
      "description": "Can you believe this junk!!  AWS Chatbot is being annoying!!  Beg your pardon.  My frustration has gotten the best of me.  Oh please sanctimonious sir will you deliver this paltry message so that I may tell my lords and ladies I completed the quest given to me?"
   }
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/custom-notifs.html) does discuss the particulars and required fields most of which have fixed values that while could be provided by AWS Chatbot.  It couldn't be bothered to do so.  Wrapping plebeian messages of such commoner usage as raw text would sully its good engineering to do so.  So conduct thyself properly when you are in its midst for only the most righteous of you shall pass.